# How many perfect squares?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many perfect squares are there between $2013$ and $3602$

WITHOUT CALCULATING, can I get some hints on how this can be done. the number will take the form $\sqrt{x}$ is an integer?

Comment: Without calculating? You mean without calculating *all* of them, or with no calculations whatsoever?

Answer (score 6):

$$44^2<2013<45^2<60^2<3602<61^2$$

I'm not sure if writing this is a calculation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you can do *some* calculating. You can see that the square root of $2013$ is $44.9$, meaning that the first number whose square is above $2013$ is $45$. The last number whose square is below $3602$ is $60$, so in total, there are $16$ numbers whose squares are between $2013$ and $3602$.